# Notification light flash rate on API 26

Tags: android, android-notifications

Before the NotificationChannel, the API to set the notification LED flash rate through a notification builder was by using this [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setLights(int,%20int,%20int)) `Notification.Builder setLights (int argb, int onMs, int offMs)`.

But now the API is deprecated and with the Notification Channel we should use this [one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#enableLights(boolean)) `void enableLights (boolean lights)` that only takes a boolean.

There is a separated [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#setlightcolor) to set the colour light but none to set the flash rate. Is there any way to control the blink duty cycle with the NotificationChannel ?

Comment: @pfx: First sentance of your link: "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code [...]"
This is not the case, this is an API question. Please avoid excessive, unmotivated downvotes.

Comment: @johand. You are right, I was not; I removed the remark.